# Initialize radio buttons with same values inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am facing issue while using radio button initialization using `ng-model`. After spending 3 hours I find the case in which it is creating problem.

`Working`

If we set different values then it works fine with `ng-repeat`. [See Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2V8hC/3/)

`Not Working`

Now, I am assigning same values for both radio buttons. It will initialize only last once.
[See Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2V8hC/4/)

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should assign different names for each radio-button groups. See jsFiddle updated link.

```
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="g in groups">
<input type="radio" ng-model="g.myrd" name="checking{{g.id}}" value="true" /> Right
<input type="radio" ng-model="g.myrd" name="chekcing{{g}}" value="false" /> Wrong
{{g.myrd}}
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/imhassan66/7H2hH/

Answer (score 1):

The radio buttons have the same name so only one of them can be checked. That's the point of radio buttons.

Your working example only "works" because you misspelled the name of the second radio button.